Is there a way to search a cell using a key word and add up values on that row?
For example, the table is like this:



Column A
Column B




asd
2


zcx
3


ddd
2



I tried with something like this =SUMIF(FIND("d",A11:A15),B11:B15)
So it should give the result a 4, but it gives a result of 0. I don't know what's wrong. I'm doing this to learn. Thanks in advance.

Your formula is
=SUMIF(A2:A4;"=*d*";B2:B4)
or
=SUMIFS(B2:B4;A2:A4;"=*d*")

where "B2:B4" is the range of cells to sum;
"A2:A4" is the range that is tested using the criterion;
"=*d*" is the criterion for search (any text with at least one "d" inside).

What I need to do is find a cells with a specific keyword on column A, then add the numbers on column B if the keyword matches on column A. Is that possible?

The first formula worked! Thank you very much! This one =SUMIF(A2:A4;"=d";B2:B4)
